# MySQL custom sort by subquery impacts performance

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have 1 table from which I return search results and display them in a a specific order. This example is an exact, simplified version of my db structure: http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/Orderbyvaluefromsubquery.htm

and here is my current code, which works but heavily impacts performance to a large extend because of the subquery used:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` AS p1
WHERE CONCAT(title,artist,creator,version) LIKE '%searchInput%'
ORDER BY 
 (SELECT
 MAX(`rating`) FROM `table` AS p2 WHERE p1.setId=p2.setId
 ) DESC
```

the above code searches and sorts the result sets by the highest rating in the set and that all rows from the same set are kept together, for example:

```
id        setId      rating       title,artist,etc...
1         1          5
2         1          5
3         2          7
4         1          6
5         2          1
6         3          3
```

would sort to:

```
id        setId      rating       title,artist,etc...
3         2          7
5         2          1
4         1          6
1         1          5
2         1          5
6         3          3
```

Currently it takes around 8.5sec to query 1000 rows and over half a minute for a large amount of rows, is there any way to improve the performance or would it be better to fetch all the results and sort them in PHP memory?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: I think your problem is not the subquery, but the LIKE operation with CONCAT. Do you used SQL explain plan of your database to be certain that the problem is the SORT operation?

Comment: I tested it without the sorting and the LIKE causes almost no performance drop (query took: 0.0264 sec), but with the sorting it becomes 8+ sec

Comment: Well, you will probably have this problem in the future :P. Try this: `SELECT t.*, max(t.rating) AS "max" FROM table as t GROUP BY t.id order by max(t.rating) desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably speed things up a bit by separating the LIKEs:

```
SELECT p1.* FROM `table` AS p1
    WHERE (title LIKE '%searchInput%')
       OR (artist LIKE '%searchInput%')
       OR (creator LIKE '%searchInput%')
       OR (version LIKE '%searchInput%')
ORDER BY 
    (SELECT MAX(`rating`) FROM `table` AS p2 WHERE p1.setId=p2.setId) DESC
```

You could also try to

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_ndx ON table(setId, rating)
```

to improve sorting performances.

Comment: adding an index really lead to a huge performance boost, now the query takes less than a second to perform (also the searching by `CONCAT()` takes pretty much exactly the same amount of time as my code)